Creating one reducer to update multiple fields in form in react Typescript using redux tool kit
I am having trouble with update form that has 5 fields to update (name, image, price, qty, info). I am trying to update the fields and have set the fields from redux store. Instead of updating local using useState, I am trying to update the store (from where I am fetching data) directly and then submitting the form. Using updateProductState reducer, I am trying to update the value field. But instead of updating it gets set to "name: name", the store data isn't getting updated.
ProductSlice.ts:
export interface ProductState {
  loading: boolean;
  products: ProductModel[];
  selectedProduct: ProductModel;
  error: string;
}

export let initialState: ProductState = {
  loading: false,
  products: [] as ProductModel[],
  selectedProduct: {} as ProductModel,
  error: ''
};

export const productSlice = createSlice( {
  name: 'product',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateProductState: ( state, action ) => {
      const { id, name, image, price, qty, info } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedProduct: {
          id,
          name,
          image,
          price,
          qty,
          info,
        } as ProductModel,
      };
    }
  }

UpdateProduct.ts:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppDispatch } from '../../../../redux/store';
import * as productActions from '../../../../redux/productsSlice';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

interface IProps{ }
interface IState {
  bigBasket: productActions.ProductState;
}

type URLParams= {
  productId: string;
}

const UpdateProduct: React.FC<IProps> = ({}) => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const { productId } = useParams<URLParams>();
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  let productState: productActions.ProductState = useSelector((store: IState) => store.bigBasket)

  let { error, loading, selectedProduct } = productState;

  useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(productActions.getSingleProductThunk(productId as string));
  }, [productId])

  let updateInput = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    dispatch(productActions.updateProductState({
      name: event.target.name,
      value:event.target.value
    }))
  }

  let updateImage = async (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | any>) => {
    let imageFile:Blob = event.target.files[0];
    let base64Image:string | ArrayBuffer = await convertBase64String(imageFile);
    dispatch(productActions.updateProductState({
      name: "image",
      value: base64Image
    }));
  };

  let convertBase64String = (imageFile:Blob):Promise<string | ArrayBuffer> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
      fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if (fileReader.result) {
          resolve(fileReader.result);
        } else {
          reject('Error Occurred');
        }
      })
    });
  };

  let submitUpdateProduct = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(productActions.updateProductThunk({
      product: selectedProduct,
      productId: productId as string,
      navigate
    }));
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {<pre>{JSON.stringify(selectedProduct)}</pre>}
      <section className='mt-3'>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header bg-secondary bg-white">
                  <p className="h4 text-white">Update Product</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body rgba-green-light">
                  <form onSubmit={submitUpdateProduct}>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <input
                        required
                        name="name"
                        value={selectedProduct.name}
                        onChange={updateInput}
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Name"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <input
                        onChange={updateImage}
                        className="form-control"
                        type="file"
                        id="formFile"
                      />
                      {selectedProduct.image &&
                        <img
                          src={selectedProduct.image}
                          alt=""
                          width="25"
                          height="25"
                        />
                      }
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <input
                        required
                        type="number"
                        name="price"
                        value={selectedProduct.price} 
                        onChange={updateInput}
                        className='form-control'
                        placeholder="Price"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <input
                        required
                        type="number"
                        name="qty"
                        value={selectedProduct.qty}
                        onChange={updateInput}
                        className='form-control'
                        placeholder='Available Quantity'
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <textarea
                        required
                        name="info"
                        value={selectedProduct.info} 
                        onChange={updateInput}
                        rows={3}
                        className='form-control'
                        placeholder="General Info"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="">
                      <input
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
                        value="Update"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default UpdateProduct


The updateInput handler is dispatching the updateProductState action and passing the field name and value that is being updated, but the updateProductState reducer is accessing what it assumes is the entire field value set.
Update the updateProductState reducer to access action.payload.name as the name of the field/property in state you want to update to action.payload.value value.
interface UpdateProductStatePayload { // *
  name: keyof ProductModel; // "id", "name", "image", "price", "qty", "info"
  value: string;
}

* Note: Tweak this interface as necessary to meet your actual state/types/etc payload needs.
export const productSlice = createSlice( {
  name: 'product',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateProductState: (state, action: PayloadAction<UpdateProductStatePayload>) => {
      const { name, value } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        selectedProduct: {
          ...state.selectedProduct,
          [name]: value,
        },
      };
    },
  },
};

Or because you can write mutable state updates use the following:
export const productSlice = createSlice( {
  name: 'product',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateProductState: (state, action: PayloadAction<UpdateProductStatePayload>) => {
      const { name, value } = action.payload;

      state.selectedProduct[name] = value;
    },
  },
};

